# RegEx for capturing and replacing an element textContent

Tags: regex, java-8

I want to replace the value of "name" node in both examples. I use regex group to match for it and replace. The grouping is working but replacing does not.

```
input 1
<xml
   <user:address>.../</user:address>
   <user:name>foo</user:name>
</xml>

input 2

<xml
   <user:address>.../</user:address>
   <street:name>bar</street:name>
</xml>


private static final String NAME_GROUP = "name";
public static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.*:name>" + "(?<" + NAME + ">.*)</.*:name>");

final Matcher nameMatcher = pattern.matcher(str);
final String s = nameMatcher.find() ? nameMatcher.group(NAME_GROUP) : null;
System.out.println(s);

//foo
//bar
```

now when I do replace

```
String output = nameMatcher.replaceFirst("hello")
 I get 
 hello</xml>
```

while I expected the following

```
<xml
       <user:address>.../</user:address>
       <user:name>hello</user:name>
    </xml>
```

For both examples. Why group is working but not replacement?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML

Comment: This is just an example. it is not about xml matching.

Comment: So you expect `replaceFirst("hello")` to magically understand that you want to replace a particular group rather than the entire match?

Comment: @Holger that is exactly my question. how would I replace based on name? I have matched found for group "name". so now I want to instruct regex to replace it.

Comment: @brainstorm: You may just use lookahead as: `str = str.replaceAll("(?<=<user:name>)(?s).+?(?=</user:name>)", "hello");`

Comment: @anubhava Is it possible for named match group replacement. what I have given is a simplified example of our exisiting code. There is a group match found by name. I want to replace it which isnt working.

Comment: The replace methods will always replace the entire match. You can use group references within the replacement string to include the match, which allows you to do things like replace everything but the group, but you can not use them to replace the group only. You could implement your own replace method. If that’s feasible, I could add an answer showing how to do that efficiently (and close to how the original replace methods works).

Comment: @Holger please provide your answer, so it is useful for a wider audience too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is an example only and you're not trying to parse XML using regex, you may use this approach. Here we are match and capture before-string and after-string in separate capture groups. In replacement we use back-references of these groups to put before-string and after-string back in final output.

```
final String str = "<xml\n" + 
        "   <name>bar</name>\n" + 
        "   <user:address>.../</user:address>\n" + 
        "   <user:name>foo</user:name>\n" + 
        "</xml>";

final String NAME_GROUP = "name";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<(?:[^:]+:)?name>)(?<" + NAME_GROUP + ">.*?)(</(?:[^:]+:)?name>)");
final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement( sb, m.group(1) + "hello" + m.group(3) );
}
m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb);
```

---

Note that following shorter code can be used for this specific case:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<(?:[^:]+:)?name>)>.*?(</(?:[^:]+:)?name>)");
final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

String repl = m.replaceAll("$1hello$2");

System.out.println(repl);
```

**Output:**

```
<xml
   <name>hello</name>
   <user:address>.../</user:address>
   <user:name>hello</user:name>
</xml>
```

Comment: curious, why did you use `<[^:]+`

Comment: `<` matches literal `<` and `[^:]` match any character that is not `:`. It is called negated character class that is considerably faster to evaluate than `.*`

Comment: The `m.group(NAME_GROUP) != null` test is obsolete; the group should never be `null`. Besides that, for this particular solution, there is no need to implement a manual replacement, i.e. `pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll("$1hello$3")` would already do the job.

Comment: Yes you're right about `m.group(NAME_GROUP) != null`. For the second part of your comment, in fact this can be achieved using `str.replaceAll("(<[^:]+:name>).*?(</[^:]+:name>)", "$1hello$3")` as well. I just showed more elaborate way as OP is probably attempting this on more complicated use-case.

Comment: @anubhava I preferred the previous solution because that fits with my existing code which I don't have much room to edit. Besides the previous one uses named Group and this one doesn't. would it be possible to have both solutions here for reference. Thanks

Comment: just to be clear, my question is how to do replacement on named group, which your previous answer had a solution. While the new solution is better, it isn't actually what I was looking for. so could you have both solutions included?

Comment: @brainstorm: ok I updated my answer with both snippets.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I will accept the answer shortly after my build is successful :)

Comment: one of the test case was failing because it had <name>foo<name>, so basically `user:` seems optional. I tried to replace with `(<[^:]+:?name>)`, but that did not work..

Comment: Instead of `(<[^:]+:name>)` use: `(<(?:[^:]+:)?name>)` where `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.

Comment: Note that `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` require `StringBuffer` or Java 9, as the support for `StringBuilder` has been added as late as Java 9. Further, `appendReplacement` will interpret group references and escape characters in the replacement string, which makes it dangerous to feed matches found in the source string back into the replacement string. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56272126/2711488) shows how to do either, insert all literally or do the necessary steps to quote the parts which should not be interpreted. This problem does not apply to `replaceAll("$1hello$2")`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that here we like to replace the name element with some new names. One way would be that we create three capturing groups, one as a left boundary for the open tag, one for the desired output that we want to replace, and the third for the closing tag:

```
(<.+?:name>)(.+?)(<\/.+?:name>)
```

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBvDWp/1/)

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lBvDWp/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(<.+?:name>)(.+?)(<\\/.+?:name>)";
final String string = "<xml\n"
     + "   <user:address>.../</user:address>\n"
     + "   <user:name>foo</user:name>\n"
     + "</xml>\n"
     + "<xml\n"
     + "   <user:address>.../</user:address>\n"
     + "   <street:name>bar</street:name>\n"
     + "</xml>\n"
     + "<xml\n"
     + "       <user:address>.../</user:address>\n"
     + "       <user:name>hello</user:name>\n"
     + "    </xml>";
final String subst = "\\1Any New Name You Wish Goes Here\\3";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

---

Edit:

If we wish to have `<name></name>` tags, we might be able to update our expression and make the first part of our tags optional:

```
(<(.+?:)?name>)(.+?)(<\/(.+?:)?name>)
```

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/KsUPii/1)

Comment: can you tell what is wrong with mine? why replace does not work but grouping works. Note I want to named group matching

Comment: btw, it is possible I can have <name>NAME<name> so (.+?) will not match the element

Answer (score 1):

The operations `replaceFirst`/`replaceAll` in `String` and `Matcher` will always replace an entire match. They boil down to an implementation like

```
public static String replace(
    CharSequence source, Pattern p, String replacement, boolean all) {

    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    if(!m.find()) return source.toString();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement); while(all && m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

Note that prior to Java 9, we have to use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` here.

When we ignore the capability to have  group references in the replacement string, we can drill down one level deeper into the logic and get

```
public static String replaceLiteral(
    CharSequence source, Pattern p, String replacement, boolean all) {

    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    if(!m.find()) return source.toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int lastEnd = 0;
    do {
        sb.append(source, lastEnd, m.start()).append(replacement);
        lastEnd = m.end();
    } while(all && m.find());
    return sb.append(source, lastEnd, source.length()).toString();
}
```

For this code, it’s quiet easy to change the logic to replace a particular named group rather than the entire match:

```
public static String replaceGroupWithLiteral(
    CharSequence source, Pattern p, String groupName, String replacement, boolean all) {

    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    if(!m.find()) return source.toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int lastEnd = 0;
    do {
        sb.append(source, lastEnd, m.start(groupName)).append(replacement);
        lastEnd = m.end(groupName);
    } while(all && m.find());
    return sb.append(source, lastEnd, source.length()).toString();
}
```

This is already sufficient to implement your example:

```
private static final String NAME_GROUP = "name";
public static final Pattern pattern
    = Pattern.compile("<.*:name>" + "(?<" + NAME_GROUP + ">.*)</.*:name>");
```

```
String input =
    "<xml\n"
  + "   <user:address>.../</user:address>\n"
  + "   <user:name>foo</user:name>\n"
  + "</xml>\n";
String s = replaceGroupWithLiteral(input, pattern, NAME_GROUP, "hello", false);
System.out.println(s);
```

```
<xml
   <user:address>.../</user:address>
   <user:name>hello</user:name>
</xml>
```

Though I’d probably use something like

```
public static final Pattern pattern
    = Pattern.compile("<([^<>:]*?:name)>" + "(?<" + NAME_GROUP + ">.*)</\\1>");
```

As said (and made clear by the method name), this differs from the ordinary regex replace operation, as it will always insert the replacement literally. Getting the same behavior as the archetype, requires more complex and less efficient code, so I’d use it only when referencing groups really is required (or the syntax is supposed to be the replacement syntax by contract).

```
public static String replaceGroup(
    CharSequence source, Pattern p, String groupName, String replacement, boolean all) {

    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    if(!m.find()) return source.toString();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do {
        int s = m.start(), gs = m.start(groupName), e = m.end(), ge = m.end(groupName);
        String prefix = s == gs? "":
            Matcher.quoteReplacement(source.subSequence(s, gs).toString());
        String suffix = e == ge? "":
            Matcher.quoteReplacement(source.subSequence(ge, e).toString());
        m.appendReplacement(sb, prefix+replacement+suffix);
    } while(all && m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

With this, if we use, e.g.

```
String s = replaceGroup(input, pattern, NAME_GROUP, "[[${"+NAME_GROUP+"}]]", false);
```

we get

```
<xml
   <user:address>.../</user:address>
   <user:name>[[foo]]</user:name>
</xml>
```